# How exactly does the Diamond Skin skill scale in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

What is the exact formula for the damage absorption value of the skill? I can see how much it absorbs at level 60, but I'm interested in the formula. Is it something like:

absorption = baseValue + gainPerLevelValue * characterLevel

or what?

I am asking for the **specific** and **concrete formula** that determines the resulting absorption value. None of the other answers really answer my question. They just post numbers that I can easily find in the official game guide.

Comment: We have some fairly strict rules when it comes to reopening questions that have been closed as duplicate.  Unfortunately, your question doesn't really qualify.  Additionally, your question borders on "asking the devs", which is something we don't allow.  If there isn't a source like a game guide or wiki that we can point to, or if it's something that can't be determined experimentally, then it's not something we can answer.

Comment: there isn't a specific formula, its a value based on the level of the character.  So the answer would then be a simple table consisting of levels and absorption values.  And since the majority of d3 content is for level 60+, the only value that really matters is the level 60 value anyway.

Comment: @MBraedley Why wouldn't this be determinable experimentally?  We know the level 60 value (10853).  I currently have a level 50 wizard for whom the value is 6350 and a level 51 at 7176.  It's not even an experiment really -- just observations.

Comment: @spartacus What about hardcore?  In hardcore, people frequently have to level from 1 to 60.

Comment: @Brythan: Is that stat listed on your character sheet (or at least determined with the character sheet)?  That's the only way I see of determining a formula.

Comment: @Brythan most of that is still done via twinking.  Leveling in hard core is almost as easy as leveling in SC

Comment: @MBraedley  It's listed on the skill tooltip.  People who have Wizards of the appropriate level can just hover over the skill in the skill bar and it gives the value.  It's not linear;  the three values I have don't fit a line.  Others have done the experiments to say that it doesn't seem to be affected by things other than level -- at least not that anyone's tried.